# partition demonstration

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$we have $A_{x}=\{x,-x\}$ is a partition of Reals? First I tried to prove that $A_{x} \cap A_{y} = \emptyset$ if $x \neq y$; i did it by contradiction: I supposed that the intersection is not empty so there is one element: $a \in A_{x} \cap A_{y}$. If $a$ is in the intersection, then it is in $A_{x} $ and in $A_{y}$; $a$ is element of $A_{x}$ means that $a$ is or $x$ or $-x$, and $a$ is element of $A_{y}$ means that $a$ is  $y$ or $-y$(then i did it by cases) 1)if $a=x$ and $a=y$ then $x=y$ but this is a contradiction because we supposed that $x \neq y$ so $a$ is not element of the intersection; 2)if $a=-x$ and $a=-y$ then $-x=-y$ and $x=y$ and this is a contradiction; 3)if $a=x$ and $a=-y$ then $x=-y$ but in this case I dont know if $x=-y$ implies a contradiction 
so I would appreciate your help in the last case :)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation). In particular, maths gets rendered only if you include it in dollar signs `$`.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=x=-y$, then, then $-x=-(-y)=y$, so $A_x=\{x,-x\}=\{-y,y\}=A_y$; the fourth case is similar.

Comment: So if I do that $A_x =A_y$ and $A_x \cap A_y \neq \varnothing$ and that completes the demonstration?

Comment: @David: I’d look at it a little differently: you’ve proved that if $A_x\cap A_y\ne\varnothing$, then $A_x=A_y$, so if $A_x\ne A_y$, then $A_x\cap A_y=\varnothing$. That almost completes the demonstration: you do still have to demonstrate that these sets cover $\Bbb R$, but this is trivial, since $x\in A_x$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: thanks you really help me :D I´ll finish it

Comment: @David: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Just define a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ by saying that
$$
x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x=\pm y
$$
and check that this is an equivalence relation.
Then, $A_x$ is merely the equivalence class of $x$.